# Books for further math self study after APs/A levels?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am almost done with my A levels ( AP's in america) and I've become very fond of math and I wish to further study it myself and not for any examination. If someone could recommend me a book regarding a topic of math they found interesting to study after their Highers were over it would be much appreciated. Also I plan on choosing computer science as my university major so I wont be introduced to the more difficult and fun areas of mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that for myself, the area of math which drew me the most was Calculus by far. In high-school, Single Variable Calculus is introduced, with such good books as

"Stewart 7e Early Transcendentals" is a good foray into Single-Variable Calculus, the study of functions of the form $f(x)$. I would also start looking into differential equations in functions of a single variable.

But why stop there? In the real world, there are several applications of Multivariable Calculus, functions of the form $f(x,y,...)$ as well as vector calculus, the study of functions of the form $\vec{f}(t)=[f_1(t),f_2(t),f_3(t)]$.

In fact, especially if you plan to go into computer science, much of electrical circuit analysis depends on equations involving vector functions, and their derivatives.

For making the transition from single variable into multivariable calculus, or even from single variable into vector calculus, and even a little of differential equations, all of Paul Dawkins Online Notes are really good places to start. There's plenty of info there. These are his calculus pages:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/CalcII.aspx
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx

Also, to go further into vector calculus/multivariable calculus, tensor calculus is a good place to jump after.

I'd recommend these books for Tensor Calculus:

http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/tensor/tensor.pdf

"Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces" by Pavel Grinfeld

Hope that's a good start! There's a lot of good stuff in the world of Math! Don't abandon it. I myself am in a Biochemical/Medical Science major at a university, but, like you still stayed curious about it. Stick with it! It'll turn up in a lot of places throughout your degree.

Comment: My A levels syllabus does include the integration/ differentiation of multiple variables along with single variable differential equations. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Anytime! Definitely if you've gone to that level, the next progression should be vector, then tensor calculus, then differential geometry. They unite alot of the ideas already found. Have fun!